# Running maven project with eclipse dependencies outside eclipse

Tags: java, maven, jetty, m2eclipse, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm developing a maven project with several modules in eclipse. The parent `pom.xml` declares all submodules, and every submodule contains a `pom.xml` with a reference to the parent. Some submodules are dependent on other submodules, so I have added them as a dependency (m2e finds them when searching for dependencies). However, when I try to run a submodule outside eclipse using jetty (`mvn -pl submodule jetty:run`), I get the error that it is missing the other submodules.

In other words, and more elaborate: there's parent, sub1 and sub2. sub2 depends on sub1. I added

```
<modules>
  <module>sub1</module>
  <module>sub2</module>
</modules>
```

in the parent and

```
<parent>
  <groupId>group</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

In both sub1 and sub2, and

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>group.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>sub1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</depdency>
```

in sub2.

When I run:

`mvn -pl sub2 jetty:run`

I get:

```
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) group.parent:sub1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

How can I get maven to find the submodule dependencies?

Comment: Have you done a mvn install before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running `mvn install` in your parent project before running Jetty in the submodule? This will install your jars in your local Maven repository, following which Maven will be able to find them.

(Or I could be grossly misreading the complexity of your question, in which case: please correct me.)